# Excel 2007 - Wrap X-Axis Labels (line break, word wrap)

Tags: excel-2007

I am not able to wrap the text of x-axis labels on Excel 2007 charts. As a result, the axis labels are overlapping onto each other. Does anyone know how can I wrap these labels?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a lot of googling we found `CHAR(10)` to be the solution of our problems.
As long as you have the value like:

```
="First Line" & CHAR(10) & "Second Line"
```

it will break
X-Axis, Y-Axis, Chart Header etc

Comment: I should note that I found you only have to do this on one label (maybe your longest), and it seems that it then automatically wraps the other labels automatically.

Comment: In some cases I've used `CHAR(13)` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the easiest way is to force a break in the spreadsheet cell with ALT+ENTER. This will carry over to the axis labels.

Comment: And if you are using Excel on Mac, do Ctrl + Cmd + Enter to add line break in the cell which will also be reflected in the chart.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of frustration, here's how I tricked Excel:

- Select the data for the x-axis in the spreadsheet.
- Create a new custom format, entering `CTRL+j` where you want a line break. (it may appear as a box or a boxed question mark, which I'll refer to as `[]` and `[?]`).
- On the chart, open the `Format Axis` dialog for the x-axis, and select `Number` from the list on the left.
- Select `Custom` in the `Category` list, and your new custom format should be available in the `Type` list.  Select it and close the `Format Axis` dialog.
- Change the format in the spreadsheet back to whatever you'd like.

For example, I have datetime values on the x-axis of a scatter plot, and I want the x-axis labels to look like

```
Thursday
April 14
12:55 PM
```

So, following the steps above, I enter `dddd[CTRL+j]mmmm d[CTRL+j]h:mm AM/PM` as a custom format in the spreadsheet.  It looks like `dddd[]mmmm d[]h:mm AM/PM` in the Type list, and `Thursday[?]April 14[?]12:55 PM` in the spreadsheet.

NOTE: if `Wrap Text` is set for the columns, the `[?]` will be replaced with a line break, but the column heights will not be automatically adjusted, so it hides all but the first row.